# libpcap "dir" filter: what do the options mean?

Tags: pcap, libpcap, bpf

In the man page of pcap-filter https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-filter.7.html, it mentions the "dir" primitive:

> **dir** *direction*
>
> True if the IEEE 802.11 frame direction matches the specified direction. Valid directions are: **nods**, **tods**, **fromds**, **dstods**, or a numeric value.

My question is: what do these valid directions mean respectively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [IEEE 802.11 frame](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ieee-802-11-mac-frame/) has 2 bits called "From DS" and "To DS". DS stands for [Distribution System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_distribution_system), which if understand correctly would be a wireless access point.

[image]

Directions have the following meaning:

| Direction | From DS | To DS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| nods | 0 | 0 |
| tods | 0 | 1 |
| fromds | 1 | 0 |
| dstods | 1 | 1 |